# How would you implement a category structure like dmoz.org

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, web

I don't have a problem with building the category structure. I have a problem trying to figure out how they included similar or other categories similar to a given one. For example, if you choose the "computers / software" category you will see a category for consumer information, games, sports, home etc. These categories don't belong directly under the software category, yet they are similar.

How would you implement something like this?

Comment: i think they built it based on keyword linking not your typical id based linking. for example: a keyword like "software" is linked to other keywords like "games", because at some level there is a relationship. From there much like google does everything related by keyword not by a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ page on DMOZ (http://www.dmoz.org/help/geninfo.html#search) :

> The ODP is a Web directory, not a search engine. Although we offer a
>   search query, the purpose of the ODP is to list and categorize web
>   sites.

According to their FAQ their content is managed by the user base, and I'd take that to include all aspects of their content and its relationships, much like Wikipedia.

That said, I don't think they're creating relationships between content categories that is served dynamically. I think they are running a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_System) and the category relationships are simply part of the content.